# AndroidX on Android Studio 3.2 - VerifyError when running app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard, androidx, android-r8

Migrated my app to AndroidX libraries on Android Studio 3.2.
When running in debug, everything works as expected but if I generate a signed APK, obfuscated using Proguard - I get this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class d.a: androidx.preference.Preference d.a.a(androidx.fragment.app.k, int)
failed to verify: androidx.preference.Preference d.a.a(androidx.fragment.app.k, int): [0x8] ‘this’ argument ‘Reference:
androidx.fragment.app.k’ not instance of ‘Reference: 
androidx.preference.B’ (declaration of ‘d.a’ appears in base.apk)
```

I've tried excluding all AndroidX libraries:

```
-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
```

But the issue continues unless I basically cancel the obfuscation using

```
-keep class com.myapp.package.** { *; }
```

Also tried looking at the mapping file for what class `d.a` is but it didn't hint me to the direction of the issue.

Jetifier is enabled

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Am I missing something here? Any chance this is an issue with the androix.preference library?

- Opened a bug on [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113798060).

Comment: are you using proguard or dexguard?

Comment: @shizhen proguard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.**

Add `android.enableR8=false` to your `project gradle.properties` file and everything will work as expected.

Notice, this is not the infamous d8 error. R8 is a new tool for code shrinking and obfuscation that replaces ProGuard, and it's enabled by default on Android Studio 3.2 canary.

**Option #2:** (This was provided by [Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113798060))

If you want to use R8 shrinker, edit your project `build.gradle` like this: (notice the r8 classpath MUST be above the build tools classpath)

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

        maven {
            url "http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw/master"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:ff9c89416cc1c8adf83d481a1e5fd515fcb893b9'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha08'
    }
}
```

Comment: commenting out the `-dontwarn` and then inspecting the ProGuard output might help to create the proper rules.

Comment: Disabling R8 using `android.enableR8=false` is not relevant as the problem is reported for ProGuard. Using a R8 master build is not a solution, and should only be used when debugging specific issues or testing specific fixes.

Comment: @sgjesse the problem is/was with R8. When it's enabled, it replaces proguard. The #2 solution was provided by Google engineer.

Answer (score 0):

**Inconsistency** of java classes between compilation time and run time may cause `java.lang.VerifyError`, 
Try **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart...** -> **Invalidate and Restart**

Comment: tried that, didn't help. There's a real issue, not just a cache bug